# compairing inputs in haskell

Tags: haskell, string-comparison

I do want to get a Tuple (String, Int) and another value a as my input in the following function:

```
getOtherPairValue :: Eq a => (String, Int) -> a -> Either a (b, a)
```

I want to compare the input a with my tuple and if the first element in my tuple doesn't match with the input a, I want to check if it matches with the second. If it doesn't match at all, I do want to return the Tuple as it is.

If the input a matches with either the string or the integer, I want to return the non matched element of my Tuple.

I tried it with the following function:

```
getOtherPairValue (s, i) e
  | e == i = Left s
  | e == s = Left i
  | e /= s && e /= i = Right (s, i)
```

Comment: `Eq a` means that `a` can be compared with `a`. You need `a` to be explicitly comparable with (or convertible to) `String` and `Int`.

Comment: Ok so I have googled a lot but I can't find how I would do that. Would you mind to give me a tipp?

Comment: It sounds like `a` should be an `Either String Int`!

Comment: What kind of values are you going to pass to that function?

Comment: By parametricity, the only possible implementation of a function with that type is `const Left`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before starting, let me tell you that this looks like a horrible idea to me. You are asking for a function taking a parameter that must be a string or a integer, then to return "the other type", and that copes with working in a typed language.

We do have something in Haskell that can achieve something similar to that, but I wonder if you really need to do that in the first place.

Anyway:

## Use `Either`

```
getOtherPairValue :: (String, Int) -> Either String Int 
                  -> Either String (Either Int (String, Int))
getOtherPairValue (s, i) (Left  e) | e == s = Right (Left i)
getOtherPairValue (s, i) (Right e) | e == i = Left s
getOtherPairValue p      _                  = Right (Right p)
```

Note the nested `Either` returned by the function. That's needed since we must return a string, an integer, or a pair. Maybe it would be wise to return a custom sum type instead.

## Tinker with type-level machinery

This is an overkill solution.

We first define "what's the other type in the tuple"

```
type family Other a where
   Other String = Int
   Other Int    = String
```

Then, we use `Typeable` to check at runtime whether the types are the same:

```
getOtherPairValue :: forall a. Typeable a 
                  => (String, Int) -> a -> Either (Other a) (String, Int)
getOtherPairValue p@(s, i) x = case (eqT @a @String, eqT @a @Int) of
   (Just Refl, _) | x == s -> Left i
   (_, Just Refl) | x == i -> Left s
   _                       -> Right p
```

This involves type families, GADTs, and `Typeable`. To me it looks tremendously complex for this operation, and this complexity is caused by having to implement a function which does not play well with types.